# Changing ownership not permitted ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I have installed ubuntu on my raspberry pi using the tutorial here https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-plex-server/

I have an exfat formatted external SSD with media on it.

I am trying to FTP to it and upload new media but doing so would throw `cannot create directory. Permission denied`

I have tried to root as root `sudo chown -R pi:pi /mnt/usb1` but again this gives another error `changing ownership of '/mnt/usb1/: Operation not permitted`.

I am begging with linux OS so I am not sure what else to do. I have searched for an answer but nothing worked.

I have tried changing the ownership and permission of the usb drive.